# missing "for loop" - pdb distance calculation

Tags: perl

I've found many posts to calculate distance between atoms, even I've written my own code for it. Now I want it to be in very less number of lines, I've written something like follows

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
@ARGV = <>;
for ( $i = 0; $i <= $#ARGV; $i++ ) {
    @temp = split( /\s+/, $ARGV[$i] );

    if ( $temp[0] eq "ATOM" and $temp[2] eq "CA" ) {
        ( $n1, $ax, $ay, $az ) = @temp[ 5, 6, 7, 8 ];
        if ( $temp[0] eq "ATOM" and $temp[2] eq "CA" ) {
            ( $n2, $bx, $by, $bz ) = @temp[ 5, 6, 7, 8 ];
        }
        $dista = sprintf( "%0.3f",
            sqrt( ( $ax - $bx )**2 + ( $ay - $by )**2 + ( $az - $bz )**2 ) );
        print "$n1\t$n2\t$dista\n";
    }
}
```

A sample input file is http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/5PTI.pdb. When I run the program it is not taking the next "CA" atom to calculate the distance, I want to calculate first "CA" to all other "CA" atoms and 2nd CA to all other CA's and so on. I know for loop is missing in my code, I tried to include that but something was going wrong. Where can I modify my code to get correct results.

Comment: Your code is wrong on so many levels that I don't even know where to start. What for `$argv`? Why put your input in `@ARGV`? Do you think `@temp` content changed in next `if` statement? Do you think less number of lines better? Do you realise you want output 1653 distances?

Comment: mistakenly I've pasted another file, the actual file I'm working with doesn't consist of `$argv` . Now `@ARGV` is for command line execution. **Yes the content in @tmp in next if is not changing(main problem)** .I dont know the less number of lines in a code better or not but I need to add another calculation part to the above code, that's why I mentioned so.

Comment: If you are going to use `@ARGV` for _command line execution_ the code `@ARGV = <>;` is not what you are looking for. It works by accident and is confusing for a reader of your code. BTW the code is supposed to communicate human to human in the first place even both of them is you, otherwise you could use machine code.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub get_ca_atom {
    my @result = split;
    return
           $result[0] eq 'ATOM'
        && $result[2] eq 'CA'
        && @result > 8 ? [ @result[ 5 .. 8 ] ] : ();
}

my @atoms = map get_ca_atom, <>;

while (@atoms) {
    my $a = shift @atoms;
    for my $b (@atoms) {
        my $dist
            = sqrt( ( $$a[1] - $$b[1] )**2
                + ( $$a[2] - $$b[2] )**2
                + ( $$a[3] - $$b[3] )**2 );
        printf "%s\t%s\t%0.3f\n", $$a[0], $$b[0], $dist;
    }
}
```

But in reality I would like to separate handling with the atom internals from the main algorithm to be clear and communicate an intention of the code as good as possible. There is nothing worse than dealing your own code after few months when written without keeping this in mind.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# handle CA ATOM record

use constant { ATOM_TAG => 0, ATOM_TYPE => 2 };
use constant ATOM_SPLICE => ( 5 .. 8 );
use constant { NAME => 0, X => 1, Y => 2, Z => 3 };

sub get_ca_atom {
    my @result = split;
    return
           $result[ATOM_TAG] eq 'ATOM'
        && $result[ATOM_TYPE] eq 'CA'
        && @result > (ATOM_SPLICE)[-1] ? [ @result[ATOM_SPLICE] ] : ();
}

sub get_name { shift->[NAME] }

sub distance {
    my ( $a, $b ) = @_;
    sqrt(     ( $$a[X] - $$b[X] )**2
            + ( $$a[Y] - $$b[Y] )**2
            + ( $$a[Z] - $$b[Z] )**2 );
}

# end of handle CA ATOM record

my @atoms = map get_ca_atom, <>;

while (@atoms) {
    my $a = shift @atoms;
    for my $b (@atoms) {
        my $dist = distance( $a, $b );
        printf "%s\t%s\t%0.3f\n", get_name($a), get_name($b), $dist;
    }
}
```

Then you can play with the main algorithm as you wish. For example above code reads all file content into memory which should not be a problem in the real task most time. But if you wish to keep only CA ATOMS just change the line with `map` to the following.

```
my @atoms;
while (<>) {
    my $atom = get_ca_atom;
    push @atoms, $atom if $atom;
}
```

As you can see, intention of the code is slowly missing with more lines but it can be opposite sometimes. The main objection to code is communicating intention even it would mean more lines of code. Especially you should not mix the low level with the high level which was the reason why I separated `distance` and `get_name` in the second code example.

If you prefer to process atoms in order as they go, you can use following code, but notice you will not save memory because you need `@atoms` stored anyway for calculating distance.

```
my @atoms;
while (<>) {
    my $atom = get_ca_atom;
    next unless $atom;
    for my $a (@atoms) {
        my $dist = distance( $atom, $a );
        printf "%s\t%s\t%0.3f\n", get_name($a), get_name($atom), $dist;
    }
    push @atoms, $atom;
}
```

Note output comes in a different order. And also note I used `next unless $atom;` instead of using `if ($atom) {` and enclosing rest of the loop in block. The reason is I want to emphasize: *Just skip it if it's not what you expect.* If you would like to surprise yourself with the third different order of output you can replace `push` with `unshift`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I will work with even more attention when dealing with these kind of things :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare all distinct pairs of atoms you need to access the file data out of order, so it is best to read all of the relevant data into memory before doing the calculations.

This program uses a `while` loop to read all of the `CA` `ATOM` numbers and positions into `@data`, and then calculates the distance between every different pair using a double nested `for` loop

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data;

while ( <> ) {
  my @fields = split;
  next unless $fields[0] eq 'ATOM' and $fields[2] eq 'CA';
  push @data, [ @fields[5..8] ];
}

for my $i (0 .. $#data-1) {
  my ($an, $ax, $ay, $az) = @{ $data[$i] };

  for my $j ($i+1 .. $#data) {
    my ($bn, $bx, $by, $bz) = @{ $data[$j] };

    my ($dx, $dy, $dz) = ($ax-$bx, $ay-$by, $az-$bz);
    my $dist = sqrt($dx*$dx + $dy*$dy + $dz*$dz);

    printf "%3d %3d  %6.3f\n", $an, $bn, $dist;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
  1   2   3.772
  1   3   6.357
  1   4   8.230
  1   5   6.883
  1   6   8.835
  1   7  11.836
  1   8  14.819
  1   9  16.272
  1  10  18.781
  1  11  22.069
  1  12  23.577
  1  13  27.304
  1  14  28.550
  1  15  30.435
  1  16  29.411
  1  17  27.994
  1  18  25.290
  1  19  23.197
  1  20  19.549
  1  21  16.377
  1  22  13.683
  1  23  10.803
  1  24  12.584
  1  25  10.300
  1  26  13.713
  1  27  14.787
  1  28  11.633
  1  29  13.140
  1  30  13.576
  1  31  16.899
  1  32  19.413
  1  33  20.494
  1  34  23.292
  1  35  22.504
  1  36  25.633
  1  37  25.598
  1  38  24.936
  1  39  22.477
  1  40  19.299
  1  41  16.005
  1  42  12.638
  1  43  11.659
  1  44  14.746
  1  45  15.146
  1  46  18.399
  1  47  17.588
  1  48  15.860
  1  49  15.021
  1  50  13.194
  1  51  11.300
  1  52  10.500
  1  53   9.874
  1  54   7.246
  1  55   5.502
  1  56   7.255
  1  57   8.869
  1  58  12.364
  2   3   3.712
  2   4   5.264
  2   5   5.705
  2   6   7.882
  2   7   9.931
  2   8  13.310
  2   9  14.660
  2  10  16.571
  2  11  19.974
  2  12  20.988
  2  13  24.611
  2  14  26.005
  2  15  28.222
  2  16  27.436
  2  17  26.450
  2  18  23.863
  2  19  22.267
  2  20  18.602
  2  21  15.926
  2  22  13.079
  2  23  10.991
  2  24  13.023
  2  25  11.272
  2  26  14.827
  2  27  16.369
  2  28  13.696
  2  29  14.802
  2  30  14.428
  2  31  17.305
  2  32  19.214
  2  33  19.670
  2  34  22.010
  2  35  20.704
  2  36  23.494
  2  37  23.285
  2  38  22.198
  2  39  19.454
  2  40  16.542
  2  41  13.059
  2  42   9.817
  2  43   9.717
  2  44  13.047
  2  45  14.062
  2  46  17.571
  2  47  17.545
  2  48  16.496
  2  49  16.013
  2  50  13.461
  2  51  11.599
  2  52  12.013
  2  53  11.355
  2  54   7.839
  2  55   6.843
  2  56   9.812
  2  57  12.211
  2  58  15.658
  3   4   3.765
  3   5   5.298
  3   6   5.675
  3   7   7.436
  3   8  11.137
  3   9  13.211
  3  10  14.962
  3  11  18.642
  3  12  19.458
  3  13  22.991
  3  14  24.871
  3  15  27.175
  3  16  26.862
  3  17  25.995
  3  18  23.864
  3  19  22.429
  3  20  18.984
  3  21  16.478
  3  22  13.154
  3  23  11.180
  3  24  12.363
  3  25  10.420
  3  26  13.564
  3  27  15.868
  3  28  13.932
  3  29  15.417
  3  30  15.143
  3  31  17.475
  3  32  19.250
  3  33  19.132
  3  34  21.369
  3  35  20.109
  3  36  22.662
  3  37  22.879
  3  38  21.582
  3  39  18.587
  3  40  15.998
  3  41  12.239
  3  42   9.840
  3  43   9.607
  3  44  13.335
  3  45  15.232
  3  46  18.951
  3  47  19.301
  3  48  18.221
  3  49  18.412
  3  50  15.954
  3  51  13.507
  3  52  14.244
  3  53  14.343
  3  54  10.830
  3  55   9.041
  3  56  11.810
  3  57  14.209
  3  58  17.229
  4   5   3.820
  4   6   5.318
  4   7   5.362
  4   8   8.786
  4   9  10.091
  4  10  11.574
  4  11  15.140
  4  12  15.971
  4  13  19.569
  4  14  21.246
  4  15  23.537
  4  16  23.146
  4  17  22.377
  4  18  20.242
  4  19  19.031
  4  20  15.631
  4  21  13.511
  4  22  10.308
  4  23   9.277
  4  24  10.980
  4  25  10.254
  4  26  13.570
  4  27  15.521
  4  28  13.857
  4  29  14.475
  4  30  13.337
  4  31  15.229
  4  32  16.434
  4  33  16.013
  4  34  17.953
  4  35  16.460
  4  36  18.973
  4  37  19.118
  4  38  17.898
  4  39  15.038
  4  40  12.292
  4  41   8.585
  4  42   6.257
  4  43   6.086
  4  44   9.793
  4  45  12.070
  4  46  15.828
  4  47  16.653
  4  48  16.036
  4  49  16.682
  4  50  13.996
  4  51  11.475
  4  52  13.125
  4  53  13.565
  4  54   9.951
  4  55   8.588
  4  56  11.858
  4  57  14.982
  4  58  17.912
  5   6   3.786
  5   7   5.549
  5   8   8.148
  5   9   9.417
  5  10  12.003
  5  11  15.345
  5  12  17.034
  5  13  20.795
  5  14  22.183
  5  15  23.943
  5  16  23.209
  5  17  21.821
  5  18  19.548
  5  19  17.663
  5  20  14.226
  5  21  11.392
  5  22   8.020
  5  23   5.923
  5  24   7.697
  5  25   6.909
  5  26  10.530
  5  27  12.000
  5  28  10.100
  5  29  10.716
  5  30   9.947
  5  31  12.216
  5  32  14.072
  5  33  14.342
  5  34  16.948
  5  35  16.188
  5  36  19.251
  5  37  19.710
  5  38  19.200
  5  39  16.885
  5  40  13.668
  5  41  10.418
  5  42   7.851
  5  43   5.721
  5  44   9.267
  5  45  10.954
  5  46  14.616
  5  47  14.695
  5  48  13.357
  5  49  14.154
  5  50  12.112
  5  51   9.007
  5  52  10.078
  5  53  11.232
  5  54   8.148
  5  55   5.688
  5  56   8.503
  5  57  11.702
  5  58  14.362
  6   7   3.831
  6   8   6.572
  6   9   9.275
  6  10  11.961
  6  11  15.547
  6  12  17.196
  6  13  20.827
  6  14  22.748
  6  15  24.452
  6  16  24.212
  6  17  22.799
  6  18  21.078
  6  19  19.207
  6  20  16.153
  6  21  13.423
  6  22   9.721
  6  23   7.486
  6  24   7.340
  6  25   5.698
  6  26   8.505
  6  27  11.057
  6  28  10.121
  6  29  11.598
  6  30  11.538
  6  31  13.190
  6  32  15.162
  6  33  14.966
  6  34  17.633
  6  35  17.217
  6  36  20.067
  6  37  21.104
  6  38  20.504
  6  39  18.040
  6  40  15.210
  6  41  11.855
  6  42  10.280
  6  43   8.110
  6  44  11.650
  6  45  13.922
  6  46  17.544
  6  47  17.700
  6  48  16.106
  6  49  17.323
  6  50  15.639
  6  51  12.259
  6  52  13.014
  6  53  14.602
  6  54  11.760
  6  55   8.788
  6  56  10.724
  6  57  13.305
  6  58  15.397
  7   8   3.788
  7   9   6.501
  7  10   8.500
  7  11  12.241
  7  12  13.561
  7  13  17.118
  7  14  19.243
  7  15  21.116
  7  16  21.202
  7  17  20.145
  7  18  18.765
  7  19  17.426
  7  20  14.643
  7  21  12.683
  7  22   9.085
  7  23   8.406
  7  24   8.404
  7  25   8.354
  7  26  10.628
  7  27  13.077
  7  28  12.781
  7  29  13.456
  7  30  12.474
  7  31  13.236
  7  32  14.271
  7  33  13.178
  7  34  15.234
  7  35  14.441
  7  36  16.903
  7  37  18.077
  7  38  17.268
  7  39  14.740
  7  40  12.239
  7  41   9.000
  7  42   8.569
  7  43   6.762
  7  44  10.022
  7  45  13.081
  7  46  16.670
  7  47  17.588
  7  48  16.646
  7  49  18.349
  7  50  16.355
  7  51  13.074
  7  52  14.771
  7  53  16.437
  7  54  13.415
  7  55  11.103
  7  56  13.508
  7  57  16.519
  7  58  18.574
  8   9   3.829
  8  10   6.391
  8  11   9.730
  8  12  11.714
  8  13  15.183
  8  14  17.246
  8  15  18.615
  8  16  18.817
  8  17  17.467
  8  18  16.564
  8  19  15.151
  8  20  12.958
  8  21  11.376
  8  22   8.076
  8  23   8.330
  8  24   7.464
  8  25   8.810
  8  26  10.170
  8  27  12.231
  8  28  12.876
  8  29  12.969
  8  30  11.707
  8  31  11.373
  8  32  11.921
  8  33  10.304
  8  34  12.345
  8  35  12.170
  8  36  14.656
  8  37  16.484
  8  38  16.239
  8  39  14.329
  8  40  11.939
  8  41   9.623
  8  42  10.141
  8  43   7.644
  8  44   9.770
  8  45  12.967
  8  46  16.144
  8  47  17.164
  8  48  16.234
  8  49  18.629
  8  50  17.098
  8  51  13.644
  8  52  15.542
  8  53  17.852
  8  54  15.331
  8  55  12.977
  8  56  14.899
  8  57  17.929
  8  58  19.411
  9  10   3.796
  9  11   6.560
  9  12   9.191
  9  13  12.815
  9  14  14.244
  9  15  15.405
  9  16  15.226
  9  17  13.799
  9  18  12.745
  9  19  11.505
  9  20   9.462
  9  21   8.624
  9  22   6.111
  9  23   8.130
  9  24   8.288
  9  25  10.836
  9  26  12.463
  9  27  13.537
  9  28  14.017
  9  29  13.030
  9  30  10.756
  9  31   9.762
  9  32   9.230
  9  33   7.106
  9  34   8.767
  9  35   8.406
  9  36  11.173
  9  37  12.963
  9  38  13.196
  9  39  11.907
  9  40   9.274
  9  41   7.975
  9  42   9.009
  9  43   6.426
  9  44   7.058
  9  45  10.329
  9  46  13.110
  9  47  14.574
  9  48  14.241
  9  49  16.984
  9  50  15.450
  9  51  12.315
  9  52  14.872
  9  53  17.243
  9  54  15.016
  9  55  13.356
  9  56  15.411
  9  57  18.781
  9  58  20.275
 10  11   3.828
 10  12   5.496
 10  13   9.172
 10  14  10.923
 10  15  12.620
 10  16  12.993
 10  17  12.458
 10  18  11.905
 10  19  11.855
 10  20  10.354
 10  21  10.795
 10  22   9.077
 10  23  11.601
 10  24  12.078
 10  25  14.440
 10  26  16.059
 10  27  17.305
 10  28  17.774
 10  29  16.703
 10  30  14.136
 10  31  12.928
 10  32  11.515
 10  33   8.580
 10  34   8.535
 10  35   6.945
 10  36   8.611
 10  37  10.409
 10  38  10.097
 10  39   8.733
 10  40   6.955
 10  41   6.570
 10  42   9.147
 10  43   8.045
 10  44   7.942
 10  45  11.516
 10  46  13.970
 10  47  16.239
 10  48  16.684
 10  49  19.362
 10  50  17.428
 10  51  14.794
 10  52  17.795
 10  53  19.775
 10  54  17.311
 10  55  16.195
 10  56  18.651
 10  57  22.165
 10  58  23.882
 11  12   3.829
 11  13   6.896
 11  14   7.832
 11  15   8.935
 11  16   9.358
 11  17   8.968
 11  18   9.167
 11  19   9.914
 11  20   9.600
 11  21  11.270
 11  22  10.756
 11  23  13.943
 11  24  14.437
 11  25  17.339
 11  26  18.680
 11  27  19.414
 11  28  20.142
 11  29  18.516
 11  30  15.604
 11  31  13.656
 11  32  11.238
 11  33   7.743
 11  34   6.051
 11  35   4.259
 11  36   5.107
 11  37   7.753
 11  38   8.381
 11  39   8.497
 11  40   7.487
 11  41   8.904
 11  42  11.750
 11  43  10.782
 11  44   9.363
 11  45  12.346
 11  46  13.858
 11  47  16.459
 11  48  17.387
 11  49  20.381
 11  50  18.730
 11  51  16.466
 11  52  19.658
 11  53  21.770
 11  54  19.716
 11  55  18.921
 11  56  21.179
 11  57  24.715
 11  58  26.195
 12  13   3.798
 12  14   5.872
 12  15   8.412
 12  16   9.787
 12  17  10.835
 12  18  11.309
 12  19  12.940
 12  20  12.564
 12  21  14.413
 12  22  13.731
 12  23  16.751
 12  24  17.446
 12  25  19.934
 12  26  21.458
 12  27  22.598
 12  28  23.145
 12  29  21.769
 12  30  18.861
 12  31  17.257
 12  32  14.923
 12  33  11.528
 12  34   9.487
 12  35   6.828
 12  36   5.623
 12  37   7.368
 12  38   6.441
 12  39   6.083
 12  40   6.825
 12  41   8.668
 12  42  12.254
 12  43  12.427
 12  44  11.299
 12  45  14.440
 12  46  16.010
 12  47  19.024
 12  48  20.323
 12  49  23.002
 12  50  20.893
 12  51  18.915
 12  52  22.282
 12  53  23.962
 12  54  21.538
 12  55  21.023
 12  56  23.674
 12  57  27.301
 12  58  29.102
 13  14   3.879
 13  15   6.705
 13  16   9.300
 13  17  11.362
 13  18  12.772
 13  19  15.105
 13  20  15.435
 13  21  17.730
 13  22  17.366
 13  23  20.477
 13  24  21.031
 13  25  23.571
 13  26  24.880
 13  27  26.028
 13  28  26.780
 13  29  25.340
 13  30  22.400
 13  31  20.523
 13  32  17.874
 13  33  14.332
 13  34  11.618
 13  35   9.221
 13  36   6.442
 13  37   8.090
 13  38   7.079
 13  39   7.719
 13  40   9.752
 13  41  12.037
 13  42  15.744
 13  43  16.183
 13  44  14.857
 13  45  17.760
 13  46  18.893
 13  47  22.081
 13  48  23.627
 13  49  26.366
 13  50  24.297
 13  51  22.512
 13  52  25.936
 13  53  27.588
 13  54  25.210
 13  55  24.803
 13  56  27.451
 13  57  31.078
 13  58  32.820
 14  15   3.805
 14  16   5.952
 14  17   8.843
 14  18  10.375
 14  19  13.401
 14  20  14.307
 14  21  17.253
 14  22  17.705
 14  23  21.206
 14  24  22.143
 14  25  25.041
 14  26  26.510
 14  27  27.150
 14  28  27.737
 14  29  25.808
 14  30  22.545
 14  31  20.510
 14  32  17.400
 14  33  14.104
 14  34  10.779
 14  35   8.226
 14  36   4.525
 14  37   5.440
 14  38   5.667
 14  39   8.155
 14  40  10.012
 14  41  13.178
 14  42  16.588
 14  43  17.017
 14  44  14.871
 14  45  17.120
 14  46  17.488
 14  47  20.842
 14  48  22.838
 14  49  25.579
 14  50  23.675
 14  51  22.349
 14  52  25.908
 14  53  27.494
 14  54  25.489
 14  55  25.493
 14  56  28.046
 14  57  31.725
 14  58  33.414
 15  16   3.763
 15  17   6.550
 15  18   9.298
 15  19  12.391
```

...etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, albeit I'm a novice to programming, I can understand this clearly as it is very similar to what I've written.